# In Ubuntu 17.10, how can I add entries to the right click context menu, like "open in terminal"?

Tags: mouse, context-menu

After updating to Ubuntu 17.10 my mouse right-click pop up menu is minimal.  This is after logging in using *Ubuntu Xorg* (see image)  How do I go about adding more entries, in particular, *Open Terminal*?  I'm now using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> which is fine, but curious how to update the pop up menu.

[image: pop up menu image]

Comment: It's because you have "show-desktop-icons" disabled. (file manager handling the desktop. If wanting then run this command in a terminal, should work. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` If this was an upgrade from 17.04 you may have other config issues as it's not best method & was never really tested. A fresh install is better ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys, for the info.  I ended up using gnome-tweak-tool, Desktop -> Show Icons slider to On.  That brought back the pop up menu entries.

Not sure what sequence of fat fingering by me ended up turning it off, but I'm back in business.  Thanks again!

Mike

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: after upgrade to 17.10 application windows did not show the context menu when right clicking in the title bar. I solved this with Gnome Tweak Tool:

Under **Windows > Action on title bar > Secondary-click** set it to **Menu**.

Answer (score 0):

The content of your "right-click" menu depends on... where you click. For instance, in Ubuntu 17.10, on your Desktop, your `Files` (your default GNOME file manager, follower of `Nautilus`) right-click menu looks like this (same as in 16.10) :
[image: Ubuntu 16.10/17.10 contextual desktop menu]

Your display server is x.Org, but are you using the default GNOME environment ?

Answer (score -1):

This is only for laptop user(using your touch pad)sorry I don't know how to do it in desktop. Base on my experienced on ubuntu17.10, yes there is no right click context menu pop-up. But I've discovered the solution for that all you have to do is to select the icon or item you prefer then tap your double finger to touch pad pointing to the selected item, then yea it will pop-up the menu..hope it helps..:)

Comment: The question is about seeing a context menu that has very few entries. You tell how to get a context menu at all.